# Showing Select filter at custom place in react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to show a simple Listing on a page using `react-bootstrap-table2`
So far i found that `react-bootstrap-table2` allows to show Select/TextBox in respective Column header.
I just want to show the Select on Top of Table instead of in respective Column Header.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import filterFactory, { textFilter,selectFilter, Comparator } from  'react-bootstrap-table2-filter';

class BTable extends React.Component {
   selectOptions = {
      0: 'good',
      1: 'Bad',
      2: 'unknown'
   };

   products = [{
                  "id":"1",
                  "name":"Arshad",
                  "price":"$ 12"
               },{
                  "id":"2",
                  "name":"Arshad 3",
                  "price":"$ 120"
               },];
   columns = [{
   dataField: 'id',
   text: 'Product ID',
      sort: true
   }, {
      dataField: 'name',
      text: 'Product Name',
      sort: true,
      filter: selectFilter({
         options: this.selectOptions
      })
   }, {
      dataField: 'price',
      text: 'Product Price'
   }];
   selectRow = {
      mode: 'checkbox',
      clickToSelect: true,
      hideSelectColumn: true,
      classes: 'selection-row'
   };
   render(){
      return (
         <div>
            <br/>
            Product Name:
            <select>
               <option></option>
               <option>Option 1</option>
               <option>Option 2</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
            <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ this.products }                  columns={ this.columns } striped
                            hover
                            condensed  filter={ filterFactory() }
                            selectRow={ this.selectRow }/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <BTable />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image: little bit pictorial explaination]
Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Even, i have the same requirement, did you find solution elsewhere?

Comment: Yes bro, actually i was asking in context to attach <select> with respective Column. So i added a <select> & created ref for respective column & write a simple line that runs on Change event of <select> this.refs.COLUMN_NAME.applyFilter("column_value_from_select_control");

Comment: @ArshadMunir please I'm new to react, how did you create a ref for the column ? if you have an exemple it will be much helpful